# Airdrop won't detect other devices

Tags: osx-el-capitan

My Macbook Pro's Airdrop won't detect other devices in the area.

I've gone through the standard system restarts, switching on an off Bluetooth & WiFi, as well as ensuring that devices are on the same WiFi network.

Upon booting up in secure boot (El Capitan), and accessing Airdrop from the Finder, the window turns black (the sidebar and menu stays visible, but the space where detected devices appear turns black). But if I were to turn off Bluetooth or WiFi, the black disappears and displays the message and button to turn on Bluetooth or WiFi.

The geniuses tell me to use a fresh install (wipe all my data) of the latest Mac OS to fix the issue. Not keen, and not fair.

How can I fix it?

Alternatively, can I repair Airdrop's code or library component? Where is it located, is it possible to delete it and possibly fix a corrupt copy of the code?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), can you please specify what is the problem with Airdrop? It might have a solution other than a fresh install of MacOS.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327154/nothing-shows-up-in-airdrop-macos-sierra Try these troubleshooting steps and also see incoming connections is allowed in Privacy and Security. also is there some antivirus blocking such attempts ? See this too https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212083/debug-airdrop-between-macbook-pro-and-iphone-6s-plus/212086#212086